# Need to show distinct items with the highest value in another column

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I'm using MongoDB in Django, and am using djongo as the database adapter. To be as specific as possible there are 4 columns being displayed on the main page: effective_date, document_title, description, and revision_number. I need to be able to show only a single distinct row for each document (using document_title), but in the same view I need to show the highest revision_number for that document_title. I have the distinct document_title working, but adding in anything related to any other column seems to either break the distinct flag, or just break the application.

The code relating to the query is:

```
class DocumentListView(generic.ListView):
    # model = Document
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Document.objects.filter(deactivated=False).values('document_title').distinct()
```

With this code the application looks like this:
[image]

Moving forward I need to be able to add in the effective_date, description, and revision_number, but ONLY for the highest revision_number relating to each document_title.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What about the remaining two columns(effective_date, description)? What do you want to display in this?

Comment: I need the effective_date and description of the document where document.document_title = max_revision_number.document_title if that makes sense. Essentially I need the date, description, and rev # matching the document with the highest available revision_number.